# Why do the calculations not work?

Tags: c#, linq

In the Linq code below, the count is 16 and the sum is 21 which are correct. However, the score always shows as 100. It should be 76.19. What is happening?

Also, I tried score = sum/count, but I can't seem to use the variable  inside the new section. Any suggestions?

```
        .GroupBy(g => g.YR_MNTH)
        .Select(x =>
            new
            {
                count = x.Count(),
                sum = x.Sum(i=>i.SCORE >= 95? 1:0),
                score = (decimal)Math.Round((decimal)(x.Sum(i => i.SCORE >= 95 ? 1 : 0) / x.Count()) * 100, 2)
            });
```

Comment: Probably because in the calculation of score an integer division is involved instead of a decimal division. BTW, `x.Sum(i=>i.SCORE >= 95? 1:0)` is equivalent to `x.Count(i => i.SCORE >= 95)`

Comment: Not sure why all the down votes without any explanation.  The user has demonstrated a problem and their attempt at a solution.

Comment: How can `sum` be higher than `count`?  The `count` is the total number and `sum` should be the number with `i.SCORE >= 95`.  It seems to me that `sum` should be less than or equal to `count`.  Did you mean that the `count` is 21 and the `sum` is 16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing math on integers results in integers.  So if you do something like this:

```
1 / 2
```

The result will *not* be `0.5`, it will just be `0`.  So this:

```
x.Sum(i => i.SCORE >= 95 ? 1 : 0) / x.Count()
```

Will result in an integer.  Later casting that integer to a decimal won't change its value after the fact.  You need to cast the individual values before performing math on them:

```
(decimal)x.Sum(i => i.SCORE >= 95 ? 1 : 0) / (decimal)x.Count()
```

Comment: technically you only need to explicitly cast one value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `x.Count()` is an `int` and `x.Sum(i=>i.SCORE >= 95? 1:0)` is an `int`.  An `int` divided by an `int` is an `int`.  21 divided by 16 in integer division is 1 which you are then multiplying by 100.  You need to move your decimal cast and place it on one of you operands inside the parenthesis; like this, for example: `(decimal)x.Sum(i => i.SCORE >= 95 ? 1 : 0)`.  A `decimal` divided by an `int` will result in a `decimal` so you will be back in business.

On a side note performing these aggregations multiple times is not the most efficient thing to do.

Comment: Could just change `1 : 0` to `1m : 0m`.  Then the `Sum` will be a `decimal` and it will all work out and no explicit casting would be needed.

Comment: @juharr - Good point.  I would imagine there are several ways of approaching this.